# Delphi 11 / RAD Studio 11 November Patch - Is it done?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Does anyone know if the last message that shows regarding "PatchTool.exe" is complete? It would appear that it is not progressing. Is it safe to cancel and restart my computer?

[image]

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-11-alexandria-november-patch-available/

[image]

I downloaded it via gettit for an automatic installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted my computer and it finished with the installation when I opened the Rad Studio/Delphi IDE. It asked if I wanted to complete the installation of the remaining components.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed to accept the UAC prompt as mentioned in the article:

> Remember you’ll need to accept the UAC Windows prompt immediately after the start of the installation process (which appears as stuck while the UAC prompt get displayed in separate window).

Comment: Yes, I did complete this step. I decided to restart my computer after waiting an hour with the last message showing as "PatchTool.exe" . All is well now.